# How to query documents in MarkLogic and process results

Tags: orm, nosql, marklogic

I've been working off of the tutorial pages but seem to have a fundamental disconnect in my thinking transitioning off of RDBMS systems.  I'm using MarkLogic and handling this database interaction through the Java API focusing on the search access via POJO method outlines in the tutorial documentation.

My reference up to this point has come from here principally:  http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/java/processing-search-results

My scenario is this:

I have a series of documents.  We'll call them 'books' for simplicity.  I'm writing these books into my DB like this:

```
   jsonDocMgr.write("/" + book.getID() + "/",
            new StringHandle(
                    "{name: \""+book.getID()+"\","+
                        "chaps: "+ book.getNumChaps()+","+
                        "pages: "+ book.getNumPages()+","+
                    "}"));
```

What I want is to execute the following type of operation:

-Query all documents with the name "book*" (as ID is represented by book0, book1, book2, etc)
where chaps > 3.  For these documents only, I want to modify the number of pages by reducing by half.

In an RDBMS, I'd use something like jdbcTemplate and get a result set for me to iterate through.  For each iteration I'd know I was working with a single record (aka a book), parse the field values from the result set, make a note of the ID, then update the DB accordingly.

With MarkLogic, I'm awash in a sea of different handlers and managers...none of which seems to follow the pattern of the ResultSet with a cursor abstraction. Ultimately I want to do a two-step operation of check the chapter count then update the page field for that specific URI.

What's the most common approach to this?  It seems like the most basic of operations...

Answer (score 1):

Try the high-level Java API and see if it works for you. Create a [multi-statement transaction](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#chapter) with a [query by example](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_33275), then use [document operations](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations).

At a lower level, the closest match to a ResultSet is the [ResultSequence](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/ResultSequence.html) class. The examples at http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/overview-summary.html are pretty good. For updates the interaction model between Java and MarkLogic is a bit different from JDBC and SQL. There is no `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` syntax.

The most efficient low-level technique is to select and update in one XQuery transaction, something like a stored procedure. However this requires good knowledge of XQuery. The other low-level approach is to use an XCC [multi-statement transaction](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xcc/concepts#id_23310), which requires a little less knowledge of XQuery.

Comment: Would it make more sense to just pull some of this logic out of the database interaction-level, then?  Execute the ORM and get my POJO, then make the mods, and update the document at the given URI?  Or, is this an anti-pattern in NoSQL-land?

Comment: If you don't mind taking a chance on someone else changing the document in between selecting it and updating it, then you could do that. However I figured you would care about atomicity, so I recommended using a multi-statement transaction in a high-level API, or in XCC, or a pure XQuery select and update operation.

Answer (score 0):

A minor issue in your code ... you definately do NOT want to end your JSON docuement URIs with "/" as you do in your sample code.   You should end them with the ".json" or some other extension or no extension but definately not "/" as that is treated specially in the server.